# How to resolve promises in AngularJS, Jasmine 2.0 when there is no $scope to force a digest?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

It seems that promises [do not resolve in Angular/Jasmine tests unless you force a `$scope.$digest()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316940/how-to-resolve-q-all-promises-in-jasmine-unit-tests).  This is silly IMO but fine, I have that working where applicable (controllers).

The situation I'm in now is I have a service which could care less about any scopes in the application, all it does it return some data from the server but the promise doesn't seem to be resolving.

```
app.service('myService', function($q) {
  return {
    getSomething: function() {
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      deferred.resolve('test');
      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
});
```

---

```
describe('Method: getSomething', function() {
  // In this case the expect()s are never executed
  it('should get something', function(done) {
    var promise = myService.getSomething();

    promise.then(function(resp) {
      expect(resp).toBe('test');      
      expect(1).toEqual(2);
    });

    done();
  });

  // This throws an error because done() is never called.
  // Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  it('should get something', function(done) {
    var promise = myService.getSomething();

    promise.then(function(resp) {
      expect(resp).toBe('test');      
      expect(1).toEqual(2);
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

What is the correct way to test this functionality?

**Edit: Solution for reference.  Apparently you are forced to inject and digest the $rootScope even if the service is not using it.**

```
  it('should get something', function($rootScope, done) {
    var promise = myService.getSomething();

    promise.then(function(resp) {
      expect(resp).toBe('test');      
    });

    $rootScope.$digest();
    done();
  });
```

Comment: I have an ng service with two functions which return different $q promises. In jasmine, I could not get the test for either function to work with any of your suggestions. I got jasmine timeout error. My .then(cb) handler in my test was calling the jasmine done handler as evidenced by console msgs around done call. Only thing that worked was $digest() in the service itself after the resolve. But to make things weirder, the second service function got an ng error saying that the "digest was already running". So I commented this digest out and all is good but no idea why. Now, that is silly.

Comment: `done` call at the end of the test doesn't make sense. The test isn't really asynchronous at this point. It should be called at the end of `.then` anonymous function. And in case the promise is truly asynchronous itself instead of calling digest once at the end it should be something like `setInterval($rootScope.$digest, 100)`

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You need to inject `$rootScope` in your test and trigger `$digest` on it.

Comment: It works but seems a bit ridiculous, I was hoping there was an alternative.  I suppose that's an issue for the Angular team.

Comment: Well, the problem is that current implementation of promises is tied to the digest cycle (actually it is non-trivial problem to solve as we don't have an equivalent of the `nextTick` method in a browser). So yes, I'm afraid that it is your only option as long as propagation of promise results is tied to the $digest cycle in AngularJS.

Comment: I tried this, but am now getting a 'No more request expected' error.

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource I have an issue to get data from controller can you please look into it. Can you help me on it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53629138/how-to-test-and-resolve-controller-data-then-function-promise-and-get-orgin

Answer (score 12):

there is always the $rootScope, use it

```
inject(function($rootScope){
myRootScope=$rootScope;
})
....

myRootScope.$digest();
```

Comment: succinct - maybe too succinct but useful nonetheless

Comment: Hi I know this is old but I've just updated to AngularJS 1.7.2 and this is no longer working. I get the error:  Error: Unexpected request: GET /api/auth/params
        error properties: Object({ $$passToExceptionHandler: true })

Answer (score 3):

So I have be struggling with this all afternoon.  After reading this post, I too felt that there was something off with the answer;it turns out there is.  None of the above answers give a clear explanation as to where and why to use `$rootScope.$digest`.  So, here is what I came up with.

First off why?  You need to use `$rootScope.$digest` whenever you are responding from a non-angular event or callback.  This would include pure DOM events, jQuery events, and other 3rd party Promise libraries other than `$q` which is part of angular.

Secondly where?  In your code, NOT your test.  There is no need to inject `$rootScope` into your test, it is only needed in your actual angular service. That is where all of the above fail to make clear what the answer is, they show `$rootScope.$digest` as being called from the test.

I hope this helps the next person that comes a long that has is same issue.

### Update

---

I deleted this post yesterday when it got voted down.  Today I continued to have this problem trying to use the answers, graciously provided above.  So, I standby my answer at the cost of reputation points, and as such , I am undeleting it.

**This is what you need in event handlers that are non-angular, and you are using $q and trying to test with Jasmine.**

```
something.on('ready', function(err) {
    $rootScope.$apply(function(){deferred.resolve()});              
});
```

> Note that it may need to be wrapped in a $timeout in some case.

```
something.on('ready', function(err) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $rootScope.$apply(function(){deferred.resolve()});    
    });     
});
```

> One more note.  In the original problem examples you are calling `done` at the wrong time. You need to call `done` inside of the `then` method (or the `catch` or `finally`), of the promise, after is resolves.  You are calling it before the promise resolves, which is causing the `it` clause to terminate.

Comment: ```$timeout``` will run ```$apply```, so I don’t believe you need to use ```$rootScope.$apply``` inside the ```$timeout```.  Try just:  ```$timeout(function(){
      deferred.resolve();    
    }); ```  N.B.:  I am hoping this will help @Jeffrey A. Gochin,  not recommending this as a solution for the OP

Comment: You know what, after playing with this for a while, I realized that the real problem is Angular is this case.  The way they implement the mocks for $timeout  are what causes this issue. My own testing, I have decided to just create my own test harness in the browser. Without angular mocks. When I do this the problem goes away.  The problem now is how to still automate the testing.

Comment: As a followup to this.  I have started using Protractor and Selenium to automate my test harness.

Answer (score 3):

From the angular documentation.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

```
it('should simulate promise', inject(function($q, $rootScope) {
  var deferred = $q.defer();
  var promise = deferred.promise;
  var resolvedValue;

  promise.then(function(value) { resolvedValue = value; });
  expect(resolvedValue).toBeUndefined();

  // Simulate resolving of promise
  deferred.resolve(123);
  // Note that the 'then' function does not get called synchronously.
  // This is because we want the promise API to always be async, whether or not
  // it got called synchronously or asynchronously.
  expect(resolvedValue).toBeUndefined();

  // Propagate promise resolution to 'then' functions using $apply().
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect(resolvedValue).toEqual(123);
}));
```

Comment: I'm doing similar in a unit test but when I call $rootScope.$apply(); it actually triggers something in a module which I though was mocked and trys to do an http GET?