# Angular JS : Not able to test service function with promises in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, tdd

Here, _fact is a reference to the service.

```
 it('Git Check', function() {
     $scope.user = 'swayams'
     var data;
      _fact.Git($scope).then(function(d) {
        expect(d.data.length).toEqual(4)
     }, function() {  expect(d).not.toBeNull(); });

    });
```

I am getting the error

```
SPEC HAS NO EXPECTATIONS Git Check
```

---

**Update**

After forcing async as per @FelisCatus and adding `$formDigest`, I am getting a different error `Error: Unexpected request: GET https://api.github.com/users/swayams/repos
No more request expected`

The updated code snippet looks something like  -

```
 it('Git Check', function(done) {
         $scope.user = 'swayams'
         var data;
          _fact.Git($scope).then(function(d) {
            expect(d.data.length).toEqual(4)
         }, function() {  expect(d).not.toBeNull(); });

        });
 $rootScope.$formDigest();
```

---

I have a [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPOX1bLUbUc2t5vXHoON?p=preview) here illustrating the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jasmine is not seeing your expectations because your function returns before any `expect()` is called. Depending on your situation, you may want to use async tests, or use some [promise matchers](https://github.com/bvaughn/jasmine-promise-matchers).

With async tests, you add an additional argument to your test function, `done`.

```
it('Git Check', function (done) {
  $scope.user = 'swayams'
  var data;
   _fact.Git($scope).then(function(d) {
     expect(d.data.length).toEqual(4);
  }, function() {  expect(d).not.toBeNull(); }).finally(done);
  $rootScope.$digest();
});
```

(Note the finally clause in the end of the promise chain.)

Please note that you have to do `$rootScope.$digest()` for the promises to resolve, even if your code is not using it. See: [How to resolve promises in AngularJS, Jasmine 2.0 when there is no $scope to force a digest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24021031/how-to-resolve-promises-in-angularjs-jasmine-2-0-when-there-is-no-scope-to-for)

Comment: I tried to implement as you have mentioned here. Got an error `Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`

Comment: Well, at least it is an async test now. I think the issue now is related to the promise not being resolved. Either it takes too long, or you forget to call $digest or something to make the promise complete.

Comment: Can you just try a simple `$timeout(30).then(function(){ expect(1+1).toEqual(2); }).finally(done)` instead? By doing so you can locate the issue in either the async and promise part, or something in your `_fact.Git`.

Comment: The $timeout.. part still triggers the same error as my service function. I have a controller where the `_fact.Git` is being used and it works fine.

Comment: Does `$timeout(done)` works? How about a straightforward `done()` call?

Comment: $timeout(done) doesnt work. done() call inside of the `it` block brings us back to the issue described in the  question. I dont have anthing around `$digest` in my implementation. I am lookig into that right now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88995/discussion-between-swayam-siddha-and-feliscatus).

Comment: I've already posted link about `$timeout`, `$rootScript.$digest()` and promises on chat. If you have more questions, please chat me. Meantime, I will try to compose these into an answer while you are AFK.