# Angular $q not working as expected - returning undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to troubleshoot a HTTP-Authentication workflow I built a few months ago. Essentially, we're storing a token and it's estimated expiration time (should be 600 seconds). If the token is not stored, a call to the API is made and a new token is registered with the server. Every HTTP call is required to use this token, so I've implemented a token-service into a custom http-service.

The first time that the token is retrieved, it submits a request with "Bearer undefined" which is strange. Subsequent requests correctly respond with the valid token.

I've added console messages to help troubleshoot this, but it's starting to make less sense. in token-storage.coffee right before we resolve the token, the console message correctly reports the token, but it still resolves with "Bearer undefined"

http-service.coffee

```
app = angular.module "grantRequest"

app.service 'httpService', ($http, $q, tokenStorage, formDataModel) ->

  httpService = this

  #load the config file which stores our API Base URL
  $http.get 'config.js'
    .then (res) ->
      httpService.baseUrl = res.data.api_base_url

  httpService.submitRequest = (data) ->
    return post('/gr/submit/', data)
  httpService.getRequest = (id) ->
    return get('/gr/get/', id)
  httpService.sendRequest = (id) ->
    return get('/gr/send/', id)

  httpService.register = () ->
    #angular $q here makes this an async function. Anything that depends on the registration will need the be put in a callback.
    return $q (resolve, reject) ->
      setTimeout (->

        #Prepare the HTTP Request
        data = { 'email': formDataModel.data.principalInvestigator.email, 'name': formDataModel.data.principalInvestigator.name }
        url = httpService.baseUrl + '/register'
        request = {
          'method': "post"
          'url': url
          'headers':
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          'data': data
        }

        $http.post(url, data)
        .success (res) ->
          #verify that the response is valid JSON and it succeeded
          if res.success
            tokenStorage.saveToken(res.jwt)
            resolve "Token was successfully saved"
          else
            #either the response was not valid JSON, or success was set to false
            reject "Either the server response was not valid JSON, or the server responded with 'no success'"
        .error (err) ->
          #HTTP error code was returned
          reject "Server responded with status code " + err.status

        return
      ), 1000 #1000ms Maximum timeout
    return

  get = (apiRoute, id) ->
    if typeof httpService.baseUrl == "string"
      url = httpService.baseUrl + apiRoute + id
      #pre-create the http request
      request =
        method: 'get'
        url: url
      getAuthHeader().then(((authHeader) ->
        #successfully retrieved an auth header
        request.headers = {}
        request.headers.Authorization = authHeader
        #submit the http request with auth headers
        $http request
      ), (error) ->
        #failed to get an auth header
        console.log 'Could not get a JWT; sending without'
        console.log error
        #submit the http request without auth headers
        $http request
      )
    else
      #baseUrl is not defined
      return $q (resolve, reject) ->
        console.log "rejecting"
        reject "Base URL is not defined"
        return



  post = (apiRoute, data) ->
    if typeof httpService.baseUrl == "string"
      url = httpService.baseUrl + apiRoute
      #pre-create the http request
      request =
        'method': "post"
        'url': url
        'data': data

      #attempt to build a HTTP Authorization header
      getAuthHeader().then(((authHeader) ->
        #successfully retrieved an auth header
        request.headers = {}
        request.headers.Authorization = authHeader
        #submit the http request with auth headers
        if request.headers.Authorization = "Bearer undefined"
          console.log 'Attempted to submit the request without a valid Token. Submitting without token.'
        return $http request
      ), (error) ->
        #failed to get an auth header
        console.log 'Could not get a JWT; sending without'
        console.log error
        #submit the http request without auth headers
        return $http request
      )
    else
      #baseUrl is not defined
      return $q (resolve, reject) ->
        console.log "rejecting"
        reject "Base URL is not defined"
        return

  getAuthHeader = () ->
    console.log "Retrieving the auth header"
    return $q (resolve, reject) ->
      setTimeout( ->

        #verify token
        if !tokenStorage.isValidToken()
          console.log "Token is not valid, registering new token."
          httpService.register()
            .then (
              console.log "Successfully registered token"
              #success callback
              ->
                token = tokenStorage.getToken()
              ),
              #failure callback
              (error) ->
                console.log "Error registering token"
                reject "Error with token registration: " + error
        else
          #a valid token is already saved
          console.log "A valid token already exists, returning token."
          token = tokenStorage.getToken()
        #return the HTTP Header for Authentication
        token = "Bearer " + tokenStorage.getToken()
        console.log "resolving with: " + token
        resolve token

        return
      , 1000) #1000MS Max timeout
    return
 return httpService
```

**Edit:** Removed token-storage factory from notes because I don't believe its relevant to the issue.

**Update 11/24**

I'm fairly certain that my nested promises are to blame here. From what I've read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26184354/q-all-and-nested-promises) if there is a nested promise, then the parent promise will *not* wait until the nested promise resolves or rejects. In this case, my $http promise is still in process by the time the httpService.register() promise completes.

I've tried to brainstorm how I might use $q.all() in order to accomplish this, but I'm only conditionally nesting promises.

I will do some more research on the behavior of promises in order to better understand this, but any insight will greatly help.

Comment: Try to narrow the problem down to smaller example.

Comment: I'm somewhat confident the problem here lies in the usage of the $q promise. Because it seems like the promises are completing and the process is running correctly but the http-service getAuthHeader() promise completes before the http-service register() promise is completely resolved, resulting in "Bearer Undefined". It feels like I have race conditions going on here, is there any way to tell angular to wait to resolve it's promise until all nested promises are complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved my own issue by reading more about promises. Probably the most helpful piece of documentation was [this blog post](http://blog.xebia.com/promises-and-design-patterns-in-angularjs/).

By correctly resolving and rejecting promises, I refactored my entire service to handle everything asynchronously, which solved all of my problems.

http-service.coffee

```
app = angular.module "grantRequest"

app.service 'httpService', ($http, $q, tokenStorage, formDataModel) ->

  httpService = this

  #load the config file which stores our API Base URL
  $http.get('config.js').then(((res)->
    httpService.baseUrl = res.data.api_base_url
  ), (error)->
    console.log "no config.js found, resorting to relative paths"
    httpService.baseUrl = ".."
  )

  httpService.submitRequest = (data) ->
    return post('/gr/submit/', data)
  httpService.getRequest = (id) ->
    return get('/gr/get/', id)
  httpService.sendRequest = (id) ->
    return get('/gr/send/', id)


  httpService.register = () ->
    deferred = $q.defer()
    promise = deferred.promise

    #prepare the HTTP Request
    data = {
      'email': formDataModel.data.principalInvestigator.email
      'name': formDataModel.data.principalInvestigator.name
    }
    url = httpService.baseUrl + '/register'

    $http.post(url, data).then(((res) ->
      console.log "register(): Received response from server"
      if res.data.success
        tokenStorage.saveToken(res.data.jwt)
        console.log "register(): Token was successfully saved"

        deferred.resolve res.data.jwt
      else
        deferred.reject "Either the server response was not valid JSON, or the server responded with 'no success'"
    ), (error)->
      deferred.reject "Server responded with the status code " + error.status
    )

    return promise

  get = (apiRoute, id) ->
    if typeof httpService.baseUrl == "string"
      url = httpService.baseUrl + apiRoute + id
      #pre-create the http request
      request =
        'method': 'get'
        'url': url

      getAuthHeader().then(((authHeader) ->
        request.headers = {}
        request.headers.Authorization = authHeader
        #submit the http request with the auth header
        return $http request
      ), (error) ->
        #submit the http request without auth headers
        return $http request
      )
    else
      #baseUrl is not defined
      return $q (resolve, reject) ->
        reject "Base URL is not defined"
        return

  post = (apiRoute, data) ->
    if typeof httpService.baseUrl == "string"
      url = httpService.baseUrl + apiRoute
      #pre-create the http request
      request =
        'method': "post"
        'url': url
        'data': data

      getAuthHeader().then(((authHeader)->
        request.headers = {}
        request.headers.Authorization = authHeader
        #submit the http request with the auth header
        return $http request
      ), (error)->
        #submit the http request without the auth header
        return $http request
      )
    else
      #baseUrl is not defined
      return $q (resolve, reject) ->
        reject "Base URL is not defined"
        return

  getAuthHeader = () ->
    #console.log "Retrieving the auth header"

    deferred = $q.defer()
    promise = deferred.promise

    if tokenStorage.isValidToken()
      #console.log "getAuthHeader(): Token is valid, returning current token."
      deferred.resolve "Bearer " + tokenStorage.getToken()
    else
      #console.log "getAuthHeader(): Token is invalid, registering new token."
      httpService.register().then(((token)->
        deferred.resolve "Bearer " + tokenStorage.getToken()
      ), (error)->
        deferred.reject error
      )
    return promise

  return httpService
```

Probably the most notable thing I learned here was that if you are within a .then() and you return a promise, the .then() will wait till the promise inside is finished before it goes off to the next .then(). Makes a lot of sense! Also, once you resolve a promise, the .then() begins executing, anything before resolution will execute first.

My favorite thing about this fix, the code is now shorter!