# How to make $q.all work in this case?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use $q.all in the code below. But I think I've misunderstood some key ideas because it's not working as I expected. If anyone could give me some pointers that would be really appreciated.

The issue is in `$q.all(toSend.pie.slices).then()`:

```
var someData = {...};
var toSend = {
    pie: {
        slices: []
    }
};

toSend.pie.slices = generatePieSlice(someData);


$q.all(toSend.pie.slices).then(function(data){
    if(data) {      
        console.log(data);  // this is undefined :(        
        //do something else
    }
});  



function generatePieSlice(data) {
    var arr = [];
    if(data) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(resp_o, resp_n){
            arr.push({
                name: resp_o.display,
                marketValue: resp_o.value,
                percentage: resp_o.percentage,
                key: resp_n
            });
        });
    }
    $q.all(arr).then(function(data) {
        if(data) {
            console.log(data); // this gives me with the correct data
            return data;
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: `$q.all` is for a collection of promises. I don't see any promises in either your `toSend.pie.slices` or `arr` arrays. Also, `generatePieSlice` doesn't return anything

Comment: @Phil, thanks for your tips, it makes sense to me theoretically, but I'm not too sure how to implement it. Can you please show me what the working code might be?

Comment: For some reason you are doing `$q.all()` twice. Omit the second call, `toSend.pie.slices` is already a promise (if you return it from `generatePieSlice`), you can invoke `.then` on it directly.

Comment: @Bergi, but I thought it's better to not manipulate a global variable directly in a function? Thats why I'm trying to return the array through the generatePieSlice function.

Comment: @muudless: Which global variable do you mean? And yes, you should definitely `return` something from your `generatePieSlice` function.

Comment: @Bergi, I meant `toSend.pie.slices`...I dont think I've understood you correctly - can you please give me a bit more info?

Comment: You're not manipulating it from within that function. You're just assigning to it the result of a function call.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84135/discussion-between-muudless-and-bergi).

Comment: *"Can you please show me what the working code might be?"* ~ No because I don't know what you're trying to do. I see no reason to use `$q` at all in your code. You have **no promises**

Comment: @Phil ok no problem, obviously I'm asking a question because I don't understand, don't have to get upset :) Thanks for your help, I will read up more about it.

Comment: you can also refer to my question to get idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16316940/how-to-resolve-q-all-promises-in-jasmine-unit-tests

Comment: @RahulR. thank you so much, thats given me a good direction for my next task!

Answer (score -3):

Thanks for all the commenters' help. This is my eventual solution for anyone else interested :)

```
var someData = {...};
var toSend = {
    pie: {
        slices: []
    }
};


$q.all({

    pieSlices: generatePieSlice(someData)

}).then(function(data){

    if(data) {      
        toSend = {
            pie: {
                slices: data.pieSlices
            }
        };

        // deferred.resolve(toSend) or something else :)
    }

});  


function generatePieSlice(response) {
    var arr = [];
    if(response) {
        angular.forEach(data, function(resp_o, resp_n){
            arr.push({
                name: resp_o.display,
                marketValue: resp_o.value,
                percentage: resp_o.percentage,
                key: resp_n
            });
        });
    }                
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: yes, but this doesn't make sense as long as you don't have any *async* operations and this is an overkill.

Comment: @code-jaff, I do have a lot of async operations happening, this is only a small piece of my code

Comment: If you're going to down vote my answer, then maybe you can provide a better answer for a more constructive response. After all, this is suppose to be a community to help each other out :)